# Add more Python libraries

Tags: python, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Is it or will it be possible to add more Python libraries than pandas, numpy and numexpr to Azure Data Lake Analytics? Specifically, we need to use xarray, matplotlib, Basemap, pyresample and SciPy when processing NetCDF files using U-SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the libs work with the deployed Python runtime, try to upload the libraries into a location in ADLS and then use `DEPLOY RESOURCE "path to lib";` in your script. I haven't tried it, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

referring to the same problem it tried the following approach leading to an error:

1. Downloading of original ExtPy assembly.
2. Using the python.exe (and pip) from UsqlPythonDeployPackage.zip to install new modules
3. Uploading new assembly by replacing the old one.

Rerunning a script (no usage of additional modules) that worked with the original ExtPy leads to the following error:

```
    DESCRIPTION
Unhandled exception from user code: "Specified verion 3.5.1 not found in runtime: C:\Windows\TEMP\65df18c5a85b421382382bebe8773472" The details includes more information including any inner exceptions and the stack trace where the exception was raised.
RESOLUTION
Make sure the bug in the user code is fixed.
DETAILS
==== Caught exception System.InvalidOperationException

   at Microsoft.MetaAnalytics.LanguageWorker.UsqlPyExecution.LocatePython(String version)

   at Microsoft.MetaAnalytics.LanguageWorker.UsqlPyExecution.InvokeLanguage(String version, String scriptname, IList`1 infiles, IList`1 outfiles)

   at Microsoft.MetaAnalytics.LanguageWorker.UsqlPyExecution.Run(IRowset input, IUpdatableRow output, String script, String version)

   at Extension.Python.Reducer.<Reduce>d__4.MoveNext()

   at ScopeEngine.SqlIpReducer<Extract_0_Data0,SV2_Aggregate_out0,ScopeEngine::KeyComparePolicy<Extract_0_Data0,11> >.GetNextRow(SqlIpReducer<Extract_0_Data0\,SV2_Aggregate_out0\,ScopeEngine::KeyComparePolicy<Extract_0_Data0\,11> >* , SV2_Aggregate_out0* output) in d:\data\ccs\jobs\628aa9d8-b2a4-430d-871c-29212456b09b_v0\sqlmanaged.h:line 2725

   at std._Func_class<void>.()(_Func_class<void>* )

   at RunAndHandleClrExceptions(function<void __cdecl(void)>* code)
ERROR
E_RUNTIME_USER_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION_FROM_USER_CODE
MESSAGE
An unhandled exception from user code has been reported
```

Comment: The problem is solved. The for the errror was most likely, that the folder contained in the UsqlPythonDeployPackage.zip was namend in my first approach "UsqlPythonDeployPackage". However it should be namend "3.5.1".